# How can I have the Twilio dialog from an SMS post only show the OK button

Tags: twilio

Although I am using the sandbox currently, is there a way to only show an OK button and not a reply as no reply is needed.  The dialog from Twilio will only show information to the user/app and not expect a reply.

Thanks.

Comment: What dialog are you talking about?

Comment: The dialog that is shown when an SMS message is sent to a phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It is not possible to change how a phone behaves when it receives an SMS message. All SMS messages are treated the same by the phone, so will allow users to respond to them from both the alert and the Messages app.

With your Twilio number, you could do a couple of different things here. I don't know your use case, but some options are:

- Ignore the replied messages. This is the easiest, but you might miss something from your users.
- Set up an automated response to let users know that they replied to an unmanned number and continue to ignore the messages. This is a bit friendlier, but I think we can do better still.
- Set up an automated response, but build a dashboard to see why people are replying to your messages. You might discover that your users want to interact with you over SMS and you can then adapt to build it into your product. You may also find that no one replies (except mistakes) and you don't have to worry about it. I think it's better to know how your users are interacting with your app though.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. you answered my question.

Comment: Cool! Would you be able to mark my answer as accepted so that others who visit the question can see? Thanks.